# MySQL Index sometimes not being used

Tags: mysql, percona

I have a table with 150k rows of data, and I have column with a `UNIQUE INDEX`, It has a type of `VARCHAR(10)` and stores 10 digit account numbers.

Now whenever I query, like a simple one:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_number LIKE '0103%'`

It results 30,000+ ROWS, and when I run a EXPLAIN on my query It shows no INDEX is used.

But when I do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_number LIKE '0104%'`

It results 4,000+ ROWS, with the INDEX used.

Anyone can explain this?

`I'm using MySQL 5.7 Percona XtraDB.`

Comment: `30k+/150k` > 20% and I guess it is faster to do table scan.

Comment: Why with 4k rows, index is being used? it is smaller than 30k though.

Comment: `Why with 4k rows, index is still not being used?` vs `It results 4,000+ ROWS, with the INDEX used.` Please decide

Comment: So if the DB engine knows when the query matches x entries it has to go over the index anyway so why not just use it instead of doing a full table scan after the index use!? Makes no sense to me, but I'm not sure how percona works.

Comment: Sorry, I ment `is used`

Comment: @xander If it will be `SELECT account_number FROM table WHERE account_number LIKE '0103%'` then it is a covering index. But with `SELECT *` it has to get all values. So for many roundtrips there is no point of using index and reference rest of data.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes but I assume the index works on the where clause, like a pointer from the account_number field (the indexed field) to the whole table row and then it doesn't matter what field you actually select. That's just index theory, in practise it may be faster to do a full table scan, hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30k+/150k > 20% and I guess it is faster to do table scan. From [8.2.1.19 Avoiding Full Table Scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html):

> The output from EXPLAIN shows ALL in the type column when **MySQL uses a full table scan to resolve a query.** This usually happens under the following conditions:
>
> You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through another column. **In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.**

If you don't need all values try to use:

```
SELECT account_number FROM table WHERE account_number LIKE '0103%'
```

instead of `SELECT *`. Then your index will become covering index and optimizer should always use it (as long as WHERE condition is SARGable).

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too, the index was also showed at possible_keys but was not used, guess I should not question the optimizer.

Comment: @JohnPangilinan The optimizer is not allways right. Sometimes it's generating really stupid plans.

Answer (score 1):

lad2025 is correct. The database is attempting to make an intelligent optimization.

Benchmark with:

```
SELECT * FROM table FORCE INDEX(table_index) WHERE account_number LIKE '0103%'
```

and see who is smarter :-) You can always try your hand at questioning the optimizer. That's what index hints are for...
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 1):

The most database uses B tree for indexing. In this case the database optimizer don't use the index because its faster to scan without index. Like @lad2025 explained.

Your database column is unique and i think your cardinality of your index is high. But since your query using the like filter the database optimizer decides for you to choose not to use the index.

You can use try force index to see the result. Your using varchar with unique index. I would choose another data type or change your index type. If your table only contains numbers change it to numbers. This will help to optimize you query a lot.

In some cases when you have to use like you can use full text index.

**If you need help with optimizing your query and table. Provide us more info and which info you want to fetch from your table.**